# Exporting a database from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, windows, phpmyadmin, backup, wampserver

My wamp server won't turn green and I want to export my database. Is there a way for me to export or get my database?

Comment: Use `mysqldump` tool.

Comment: thank you. but can you tell me on how to do it? I do not know how.

Comment: my DB does not have a password or username.

Comment: Skip username and password.

Comment: Whan WAMPServer's icon does not turn green, it means that either Apache or MySQL has not started, which service has not started? If its MySQL that has not started, then you will not be able to access your databases as MySQL is not there to action ANY requests. So if MySQL has not started you had better ask some questions about WHY.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your mysql/bin folder and in the cmd execute this

```
 mysqldump -uroot -p --opt --skip-set-charset --all-databases > backup.sql
```

Read more at:

- http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,67205,67205
- https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/25599/60862
- https://snippetsofcode.wordpress.com/2011/08/02/howto-dump-mysql-database-on-wamp/

Comment: If MySQL is the service that is not running I dont think this will help.

Comment: is true, but the question don't says any about this. we most wait for the answer to your question in the comments